# PHPExcel Can you remove borders

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to build an excel file of a schedule. I initially create each shift as a column and use borders to separate the intervals.

Then I want to set the tasks by coloring the background. Those cells that have tasks (i.e. background color), I want to remove the borders.

Since I am making the Excel file, I cannot use getFill() to find the cell background color before I save the file and open it!

What can I do?

Comment: set the border color to the same as fill color

Comment: Thanks!! Don't know why I didn't think of that!!

Comment: @DevZer0 - why not post as an answer?